# Nginx suffix meaning

Tags: nginx, naming

As I was reading the Nginx source code. I often came across variable names ending with _t (for example: `ngx_http_request_t`) and _s (`ngx_http_request_s`). Can anyone explain what t and s means?

Comment: In `ngx_http.h` is the line `typedef struct ngx_http_request_s ngx_http_request_t;`. So I guess one is a struct and the other is a typedef of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Nginx's official Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html

> Type names end with the “_t” suffix.

_t means "type"

> A structure that points to itself has the name, ending with “_s”.

_s means "self"